# Relative Lorentz factor for two shells

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

Shell 1 is travelling at a speed $v_1$ with Lorentz factor $\Gamma_1$, and shell 2 at speed $v_2$ with Lorentz factor $\Gamma_2$. Just before the two shells meet, the relative lorentz factor $\Gamma_r$ is given by:
$$\gamma_r = \Gamma_1 \Gamma_2 (1-v_1v_2/c^2) $$

as detailed in equation 141 of page 102 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0679).

Can anyone explain why this should be so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Lorentz Boost parameter ($\lambda$) for each shell, where

$$ v/c=\tanh(\lambda) $$
$$ \gamma = \cosh(\lambda) $$
$$ \beta \gamma = \sinh(\lambda) $$

For boosts in the same direction the boost parameters just add or subtract.  So $\lambda_1 -\lambda_2$ is the boost with which one shell is approaching the other.  Consider the trigonometric identity

$$ \cosh(\lambda_1 -\lambda_2)= \cosh(\lambda_1) \cosh(\lambda_2)- \sinh(\lambda_1) \sinh(\lambda_2) $$
$$ = \cosh(\lambda_1) \cosh(\lambda_2)(1- \tanh(\lambda_1) \tanh(\lambda_2)) $$

Then putting $\gamma$ and $v/c$ in for cosh and tanh gives

$$ \gamma_{12}=\gamma_1 \gamma_2 (1-(v_1/c)(v_2/c)) $$

Using Lorentz Boost parameters makes most Special Relativity problems much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Lorentz Transformation  $\:O x y z \longrightarrow O_1 x_1 y_1 z_1\:$  and its inverse $\:O_1 x_1 y_1 z_1 \longrightarrow  O x y z \:$, $\:\left(y_1 = y, z_1 = z\right)\:$

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1\\
   \\
   \\
  c t_1
\end{bmatrix}
= \gamma_1
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  -\dfrac{v_1}{c}\\
  & \\
  -\dfrac{v_1}{c} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
   \\
   \\
  c t
\end{bmatrix}
\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
   \\
   \\
  c t
\end{bmatrix}
=\gamma_1
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \dfrac{v_1}{c}\\
  & \\
  \dfrac{v_1}{c} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1\\
   \\
   \\
 c t_1
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
Lorentz Transformation  $\:O x y z \longrightarrow O_2 x_2 y_2 z_2\:$,  $\:\left(y_2 = y, z_2 = z\right)\:$  and its composition with  $\:O_1 x_1 y_1 z_1 \longrightarrow  O x y z \:$

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_2\\
   \\
   \\
 c t_2
\end{bmatrix}
= \gamma_2
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -\dfrac{v_2}{c}\\
  & \\
  -\dfrac{v_2}{c} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
   \\
   \\
 c t
\end{bmatrix}
=\gamma_2
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  -\dfrac{v_2}{c}\\
  & \\
  -\dfrac{v_2}{c^2} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\gamma_1
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \dfrac{v_1}{c}\\
  & \\
  \dfrac{v_1}{c} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1\\
   \\
   \\
 c t_1
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
So,

Lorentz Transformation  $\:O_1 x_1 y_1 z_1 \longrightarrow O_2 x_2 y_2 z_2\:$,
$\:\left(y_2 = y_1, z_2 = z_1\right)\:$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_2\\
   \\
   \\
   \\
   \\
 c t_2
\end{bmatrix}
= \gamma_1 \gamma_2\left(1-\dfrac{v_1 v_2}{c^2} \right)
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & - \dfrac {\left(v_2 - v_1\right)}{c\left(1-\dfrac{v_1 v_2}{c^2}\right)}\\
  & \\
 - \dfrac {\left(v_2 - v_1\right)}{c\left(1-\dfrac{v_1 v_2}{c^2}\right)} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1\\
   \\
   \\
   \\
   \\
 c t_1
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
that is the velocity of $\:O_2 x_2 y_2 z_2\:$ relative to  $\:O_1 x_1 y_1 z_1\:$ is

\begin{equation}
 v_{2\: relative\; to\: 1}= v_{21}=\dfrac {v_2 - v_1}{1-\dfrac{v_1 v_2}{c^2} }
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
with $\:\gamma-$factor
\begin{equation}
 \gamma_{21}=\left[1-\left(\dfrac { v_{21}}{c}\right)^{2}\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}  =\left[1-\left(\dfrac{\dfrac {v_2 - v_1}{1-\dfrac{v_1 v_2}{c^2}}}{c}\right)^{2}\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}= \gamma_1 \gamma_2\left(1-\dfrac{v_1 v_2}{c^2} \right)
\tag{05}
\end{equation}

There exists a quantity called **rapidity** defined by $\:\cosh \zeta = \gamma \:$, that is

\begin{equation}
\zeta =\cosh^{-1}\gamma =\cosh^{-1}\left[\left(1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right]
\tag{06}
\end{equation}

Of course
\begin{equation}
\tanh \zeta = \dfrac{v}{c}
\tag{07}
\end{equation}

Having in mind that
\begin{equation}
\cosh \zeta = \cos \left(i\zeta\right)\;, \quad  \sinh \zeta = -i\sin \left(i\zeta\right)
\tag{08}
\end{equation}

equation (01) is expressed as

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1\\
     \\
 i c t_1
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos \left(i\zeta_1 \right) & - \sin \left(i\zeta_1 \right)\\
  & \\
  \sin \left(i\zeta_1 \right) & \cos \left(i\zeta\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
   \\
 i c t
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}

or defining like an angle 
\begin{equation}
\theta_1 = i\zeta_1
\tag{10}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1\\
     \\
 i c t_1
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos \theta_1  & - \sin \theta_1 \\
  & \\
  \sin \theta_1  & \cos \theta_1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
   \\
 i c t
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}

which reminds us a rotation through the (imaginary) angle $\:\theta_1 \:$.

Then equation (05) for the $\:\gamma-$factor is the well-known identity for the $\:\cos \left(\theta_2 - \theta_1\right)\:$

\begin{equation}
\cos \left(\theta_2 - \theta_1\right)=\cos \theta_2 \cos \theta_1 + \sin \theta_2 \sin \theta_1 
\tag{12}
\end{equation}

---

[image: SR 1]

[image: SR 1 3d]

[image: SR 2 3d]